# Can Deep Learning predict Encryption Keys in Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman Ephemeral

Tags: ecc, machine-learning

I was talking to my friend who is building an AI startup, and his premise was Deep Learning, can somehow be used, to predict, when fed the correct data (input) and run for multiple (n; n = large) iterations, can predict break encryption, whereas I said, that something like Elliptic curve would be hard to predict and because the observables in Elliptic Curve DHE are highly uncorrelated, and would be hard to predict using Machine learning. I would appreciate any opinion on this.

Comment: Asking for an opinion is often a good way to get the question closed as "Opinion Based"

Answer (score 2):

The cornerstone of encryption is that the keys are not predictable by an attacker. That's why these keys are derived using robust ("cryptographically secure") random data. Such cryptograhically secure random generators often have physical randomness as entropy source. For more see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

The very point of randomness though is that there is no pattern behind it. Not having any pattern in the first place means of course that no pattern can be be learned. And if there is nothing to learn then it does not matter what learning method is used, this includes deep learning.

This does not mean that such algorithms are useless when attacking cryptographic implementations. They might be used for detecting unexpected pattern caused by broken randomness or broken implementations. They can also be helpful to detect pattern in the side channels of implementations (i.e. fluctuations in power usage, timing, ...) which then can be used to extract existing cryptographic material. For more on this search for example for [attacking cryptographic implementations with deep learning](https://www.google.com/search?q=attacking+cryptographic+implementations+with+deep+learning).

Comment: Further information on machine learning cryptanalysis can be found in [Aron Gohr's 2019 paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-26951-7_6) and the [related work](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=6584969566627321683&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very comprehensive and insightful response. Appreciate your input.